# Apply node module with object prototype methods

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Good morning.
I'm trying to create a node module witch right now is published as `redgem`.
It consists of adding methods to base objects prototypes. For example:

```
const obj = { a: 'b', c: 'd' }
obj.map(do stuff)
```

However i haven't found a good way to apply these methods in a project. If i run the tests (they are inside the module) they all run smoothly since methods are added to base objects (arrays, strings and actual objects). But if i do the same thing in another project i get errors like Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.
Could anyone please help me setup the package?

The way i'm trying to use redgem in projects right now is:

```
import redgem from 'redgem';
redgem():
```

Thanks.

---

So, basically this is how i export the module:

```
export default function apply () {
    stringMethods.forEach((method) => {
        String.prototype[method.name] = method.function
    })

    arrayMethods.forEach((method) => {
        Array.prototype[method.name] = method.function
    })

    objectMethods.forEach((method) => {
        Object.prototype[method.name] = method.function
    })
}
```

Where every method is in the following form

```
    {
        // Tells wether the array is empty.
        name: 'empty',
        function: function () {
            return this.length == 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your export

Comment: Done, sorry for forgetting.